# Javascript & HTML basics for school

Tags: javascript, html

I'm literally a complete newbie when it comes to JS and Ive gotten a question from school that I cannot make sense of. I've gotten a bit in, but would really appreciaete some tips/help as I'm totally stuck! 
It goes more or less as follows:
Render a webpage using HTML5 that requests a user to enter their birth year and current year.
When the user clicks on the button, a JS function is invoked
The function should take the user inputs as parameters and calculate the possible age
If user inputs are invalid, an error message should be displayed on screen (I haven't even gotten this far!)
My attempt so far is as follows:

```
<head>


</head>

<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function calculateAge()
    {
        var birthyear= document.form.text.birthyear.value;
        var currentyear= document.form.text.currentyear.value;
        var sum= birthyear - currentyear;


        document.write=("<button onclick="calculateAge()">Calculate Age"You are either " + sum " or " + sum + 1)</button>

    }

    </script>


        <form>
            Birth Year
            <input type="text" name="birthyear">
            <br> <br>
            Current Year
            <input type="text" name="currentyear">
            <br><br>
            <button onclick="calculateAge()">Calculate Age</button>
        </form>



</body>
```

Any/all help would be REALLY apppreciated, I think once I see the code written properly for the questions asked it will majorly help in my understanding of things...
Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this one.

```
<head>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    function calculateAge()
    {
        var birthyear= document.myform.birthyear.value;
        var currentyear= document.myform.currentyear.value;
        var sum= birthyear - currentyear;


        document.write("Calculate Age=You are either " + sum +" or " + (sum + 1));

    }

    </script>

</head>

<body>



        <form name="myform">
            Birth Year
            <input type="text" name="birthyear">
            <br> <br>
            Current Year
            <input type="text" name="currentyear">
            <br><br>
            <input type="button" onclick="calculateAge()" value="Calculate Age"/>
        </form>



</body>
```

Comment: That seems to be exactly it mate, thanks so much! I'm going to compare what I had written to yours and see what I was doing wrong. Thanks again

Comment: @MarkoD in the above code , form has been given an attribute name. using that the input are being retrieved , thats the difference in his and ur code

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Sample

https://jsfiddle.net/a68dc1pk/

```
function calculateAge() {
    //alert(document.getElementById("birthyear").value);
    var birthyear= document.getElementById("birthyear").value
    var currentyear= document.getElementById("currentyear").value
    var sum= currentyear - birthyear;
    alert(sum);
}
```

Remove your form tag

```
Birth Year
        <input type="text" id = "birthyear" value="1990" name="birthyear">
        <br> <br>
        Current Year
        <input type="text" value="2015" id = "currentyear" name="currentyear">
        <br><br>
        <button onclick="calculateAge()">Calculate Age</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a mill for the helpful advice Nidhin.

Comment: @MarkoD glad i could help :), if possible upvote the two answers

Comment: Seemingly the upvote comes into effect once I've reached level 15 Reputation, but rest assured I will when that happens.